# Axios GET request fails to hit endpoint without params object

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am making a request to a custom endpoint...

```
VideoAPI.get('/api/getVideo/:id', function(req, res){
  console.log('FROM URL STRING', req.params)
  console.log('FROM PARAMS OBJECT', req.query)
  res.end()
}
```

If if make an Axios post like so, it never hits the endpoint and I get a 300 status response client side:

```
axios.get(`/api/getVideo/2`)
  .then( res => {
   console.log(res)
  })
```

But if I make the call like so, it hits the endpoint as expected, even if the params object is completely irrelevant data:

```
 axios.get(`/api/getVideo/2`, {
   params : {
    bogus: 'WTF'
   }
 })
.then( res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

My console will read:

```
FROM URL STRING { id: '2' }
FROM PARAMS OBJECT { bogus: 'WTF' }
```

What am I not understanding here?